# Linux, Hard drive : how to avoid read failures from USB adapter after first error

Tags: linux, usb, sata, ddrescue

I regularly try to save data from failing hard drives. I use a sata USB adapter, and ddrescue.
The issue is that when it encounter a bad sector, it result in a read error, and all next read will also return an error. So I have to turn off and on the adapter to continue the rescue.
I do not have this issue if I plug the drive directly to the motherboard SATA port, but this is not convenient.

Is there a way, maybe a linux option to access the drive differently (I already tried the direct access option from ddrescue) ? Is it the fault of the adapter (I tested two), or the USB connection ?

Thank you

Comment: Similar: [`ddrescue` from drive intermittantly cutting out, ways to automate power cycling via software](https://superuser.com/q/1105376/432690). The asker there did not mention even trying to connect the drive directly, so I'm not sure it's exactly the same problem. Anyway, there are few answers there; check them.

Comment: Unfortunatly it did not help. The scterc do not change anything, and I do not want to powercycle the harddrive (it would make the recovery way longer). I would like to avoid the infinite read error after the first one, just like when it's attached to sata port on the motherboard